# require is not defined error when hosting website on netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, netlify, react-chat-engine

I tried to host my first Vite/react website on netlify. first time it got error of mime type but after some time i get another error that says `"require is not defined"`. How can I solve this problem?

P.s   for the build command I used `"CI=false Vite build"` and I also have implemented chatengine inside of my code

I don't know much about this error so mostly I tried rebuilding it again

Comment: I also tried vite with chat engine and it doesn't work well after build